# Simple way to parse this tree-based data file into a flat-file csv

Tags: unix, text

I have a text file that is not in a standardized format, but that outputs data in a predictable tree-like way.

It looks something like this:

```
#group 0 size: 4 bs: 7.49113e-101
0 1 2 7 
#group 1 size: 3 bs: 5.31707e-101
3 4 8 
#group 2 size: 2 bs: 6.2351e-101
5 6 
#group 3 size: 1 bs: 1
9
```

Here entries in this text file are groups, followed by their size, a score, and labels of the items. In the first case: group 0 contains labels 0, 1, 2, 7 (thus, it has a size of 4) and has a score of 7.49113e-101.

I'm wondering how I can parse such a text file into a flat-file csv that looks something like this:

```
group | item | score  
0 0 7.49113e-101  
0 1 7.49113e-101  
0 2 7.49113e-101  
0 7 7.49113e-101  
1 3 5.31707e-101  
...
```

I'm not looking for code - just need to know what language I could use to do this in the simplest way on a Unix-system.

Comment: Ruby, Perl, Python would do it easiest, and are available on all modern Unices. Under 10 lines of code or so.

Comment: awk would be worth a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk can do the job:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "group", "item", "score"}
     $1=="#group"{g=$2; s=$6; next} {for(i=1; i<NF; i++) print g, $i, s;}' data
```